Error in Visual Studio when running a SSIS package
I need to export data from Oracle to SQL Server.
To do this, I have built a dtsx package in SQL Server 2019.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 (64bit) and an SSIS solution.
On Oracle I use "Oracle in OraClient 11g_home1" (also 64bit).
There I use the "Execute Package Task" to run the package.
When I try to preview a table (any table!), I get the following message:

Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow (System.Data)

On other systems, where everything was 32bit, this worked fine.
Does this have something to do with the 64bit?
where is the problem?
